# Nautilus icon view as default in a specific folder

Tags: icons, nautilus-elementary

I would like to set a few of my folders with a specified zoom level and set to icon view (e.g. my ebook folder) Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Nautilus does this by default ... I don't see anything in the settings that would enable or disable this functionality.

Comment: Hmmm very odd, my nautilus most certainly doesn't. I should also probably note that i use nautilus elementary...

Comment: It seems that remembering settings on a "per folder" basis may be non-elementary my dear Watson.

Comment: No, I reinstalled ubuntu and now its all working fine. I had a problem with symlinks all over the system. I wonder if that had broken the folder properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the zoom level and set to icon view in specific folder, it will "remember" this up to a large but finite number of folders.