# How do I set default view to 'list' in Nautilus file manager?

Tags: nautilus, customization, filemanager

I would like to set my Nautilus "Default view" to **List** globally on my PC.

Is this possible, if so, how do I achieve this?

[Linked Question (old)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4873/nautilus-icon-view-as-default-in-a-specific-folder)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

First, reset all previous folder view preferences by deleting `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata` [(source)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164551/how-to-reset-all-per-folder-view-settings-in-nautilus)

Next, open Nautilus and select `Edit -> Preferences -> Views (tab) -> View new folders using` , and change to `List View`:

[image: Nautilus prefs dialogue]

Comment: Note that the original question asked about **Globally** changing the view, and the answer here changes it **for the active user**. I think that's what they meant anyway.

Comment: In 12.04 I skipped the deleting metadata part because, seriously, why use gui and also manually do bizarre non-gui things. After that simply clicking away and back to the displayed folder updated it to List View.

Comment: I suggest the answer should be updated and "_reset all previous folder view preferences_" should be removed.

Comment: There is no Edit-Preferences-views in 16.04

Comment: 2016 Gnome.  This is outdated.. see last post for dconf editor solution...  no command line needed.

Comment: @frepie, you're wrong. Once Files is open, you get to the menu by going to 'Files' => 'Preferences' on the black bar, which will then open the GUI.

Answer (score 28):

For everyone who likes to do things by terminal changing the settings for nautilus can be done by

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-folder-viewer 'list-view'
```

If you need to find out which settings are applied to nautilus you can go

```
gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-folder-viewer
```

The credits for this post go to:
https://scivision.co/ubuntu-setting-nautilus-default-view-to-detailed-list-view/

Comment: Excellent answer, works on Ubuntu 16.04 and is a much faster alternative to the accepted answ.

Answer (score 9):

Other possible way of solving this is through *dconf* Editor, see `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences` and **`default-folder-viewer`** there.

[image: prefs picture]

This means there would be a simple one-line expression to change this, so you can include it easily to your config/setup scripts. [See more on *dconf*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it).

Comment: Thanks!  This is the way it should be done.. I do not know why gnome does not have a menu to do this.  However, it was easy.. Goes to show why people do not use ubuntu!  :)

Comment: This method worked for Nautilus 3.20 on Ubuntu 17.04, whereas the preceding methods did not.

Answer (score 5):

For Gnome 2, the following should be enough:

```
sudo gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --type string --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/default_folder_viewer list_view
```

Other possible values are `icon_view` and `compact_view`

For Ubuntu 12.04 and similar Unity-based UI, edit `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml` file: find the `default-folder-viewer` key and replace its `<default>` tag value by `'list-view'`