# Windows explorer-like file manager for Linux with "List" view style

Tags: windows, filemanager

Is there any file manager for Linux with a view style similar to that of "List" in Windows Explorer? i.e: in the screenshot I have set it to "List" and sorted by type. In my couple decades of checking out Linux distros every now and then I've yet to see this feature in the file managers.

[image]

Comment: Every Nautilus clone (aka every popular file manager on linux) has this; it's typically called "compact".

Comment: Where is such option? http://i.imgur.com/KyuZmYf.png

Comment: See the icon with 9×9 dots in the top right corner?

Comment: that's not list style like in windows

Comment: Thunar has it too, called "Compact List"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

This is the Caja file manager (a fork of Nautilus, Unity's file manager) in Ubuntu MATE, which uses Gnome 2, but it's very much the same deal with Gnome 3 (Nemo), or KDE (Dolphin).

Note the dialogue in the top middle that says "Compact": Its other two options are "List" and "Icon". Nautilus has the functionality, except with different looking buttons.

[In the application's preferences, you can configure the default view for folders.](https://askubuntu.com/a/134380/455520)

I'm pretty sure almost any file manager you can possibly find for Linux will have this functionality, with perhaps the exception of [Midnight Commander](http://midnight-commander.org) but that's because it's text-based and already awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Nautlius v3.10+ doesn't have the compact view any longer. You can [try Nemo](/q/517515/175814), a Nautilus fork for Cinnamon (a DE based on Gnome/GTK+ 3), instead.

[image: Nemo compact view]

Comment: What do you mean, "Nautilus doesn't have the compact view any longer?" I don't believe this, at all. Furthermore, Nemo is Cinnamon's, not Pantheon's, and by extension, GNOME's, not Elementary's.

Comment: [This](//i.imgur.com/9dohIfS.png) is Nautilus on my system. No compact view. I was [looking to get it back](/q/285461/175814) but settled with Nemo after reading from multiple sources, it was removed. I'll fix the description of Nemo.