# How do you change from icon to list view in 20.4

Tags: nautilus

It must be there somewhere but it eludes me at the moment.

Comment: Accepted answer in Question marked as duplicate is currently obsolete! Options that formerly were in the "Application Menu" (in the Gnome Shell top bar) now returned to the application window.

Comment: @vanadium Would it make sense to add a version 20.04 answer to the duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for list view, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for icon view.

There is also the "Toggle view" icon (left from the down-pointing arrow "View options" in the top row), in case you prefer the mouse.

Comment: I think you mean headerbar, not top bar. A screenshot would be nice too.

Comment: @vanadium Would you like to post your answer on [How do I set default view to 'list' in Nautilus file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/q/134371) as  well?

Comment: @Kulfy the format of this site causes old questions to be cultivated. The answers to that question are fully obsolete by now. Few will scroll down to find an up to date answer at the bottom of the page. I consider this a problem with the format of this Q&A site.

Comment: @vanadium I linked another more specific question as opposed to the current duplicate target of this question. Though the accepted answer is outdated but the [answer that suggests using `gsettings`](/a/788039) is still applicable and was posted 4 years later. Another example is [one of my answer](/a/1072894) which was posted 6 years after the highest voted answer was posted and now is the 2nd highest voted (I know the difference in votes ~60 but I don't think that matters much). I generally tend to allow the votes to determine the quality and applicability of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an icon in the toolbar at the top: several lines with a dot and dash.